# Where does Laravel's Artisan get session config info from?

Tags: session, caching, laravel, memcached, ratchet

My session config file says to use memcached, but all artisan commands are loading the "array" driver instead. I'm writing a web sockets application with Ratchet and need to connect to Memcached to get the user's session information, but seems to ignore my config.

Where and how does Laravel determine which session drivers to use for Artisan commands?

Comment: You need to specify the environment variable `--env` when you run artisan. Check the docs for more info http://laravel.com/docs/artisan

Comment: @TheShiftExchange I ran `App::environment()` within the command and it showed 'local', which is the same as the rest of my application, so I doubt that's it.

Comment: Hmmm... in that case I wonder if the artisan command is hardcoded to use an array session - since you would not normally want to access a session via artisan...

Comment: @TheShiftExchange not sure... that would be very strange there. I should be able to tell it what to load.

Comment: Maybe. But *normally* you would never use a session within Artisan. The whole point is to run one off commands - not to interact or maintain session information.

Comment: In fact - now that I re-read your question, it doesnt make much sense. Why are you trying to get Artisan to interact with a users current session? What data from the users session do you specifically need?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange the artisan command acts as a chat server, not unlike https://medium.com/laravel-4/laravel-4-real-time-chat-eaa550829538. When a user connects, he immediately sends a websocket message with his session id, which I look up to make sure he's a legit logged in user and to grab his user id. That's why I'm getting the user sessions from the artisan (chat) command. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider\SessionServiceProvider::setupDefaultDriver()` Laravel will set the session driver to array if running in console.
You can easily override this by registering your custom service provider. Create a custom service provider, extend the default session service provider and override the method `setupDefaultDriver)`. Here is my custom service provider for example:

```
<?php namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider as DefaultSessionProvider;

class SessionServiceProvider extends DefaultSessionProvider
{
    protected function setupDefaultDriver() {}
}
```

Then open up `config/app.php` and replace `'Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider'` with `'App\Console\SessionServiceProvider'`.

Now artisan will also use the same session storage as Laravel app.

Since you are trying to attach the session to Ratchet, You can directly inject this session instance into Ratchet app:

```
$session = new \Ratchet\Session\SessionProvider(
    new MyCustomRatchetApp(),
    $this->getLaravel()['session.store']
);

$server = new \Ratchet\App('localhost');
$server->route('/sessDemo', $session);
$server->run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Gufran posted a good answer, but another solution which doesn't involve swapping out a service provider, it just to set the default driver manually in your artisan command (or tests).

Like so: `Session::setDefaultDriver('memcached');`. You can do the same for cache: `Cache::setDefaultDriver('memcached');`. You do this before doing any other commands, of course, so that it doesn't start using the array.

If you need to, you can manually put in connection information: `Config::set('cache.memcached', array(array('host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => 12345, 'weight' => 100)));`